# Sequelize / Typescript / Graphql clashing on ID as Int vs String

Tags: typescript, graphql, sequelize.js

I've created an Apollo Server that is underpinned by Sequelize.

I'm also writing my application in TypeScript.

This has created a clash between Sequelize's notion of a primary key (an Int) versus GraphQL's notion of an ID (a special string).

Specfically, I have a GQL type that looks like this:

```
type Book {
    id: ID!
    Title: String!
  }
```

And a Typescript interface that looks roughly like this:

```
export interface Book extends Model {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

In my resolver, I have the following:

```
book: async (parent, args, context) => {
      const { models } = context;
      const { id } = args;
      const carrier = await models.Book.findByPk(id);
      return carrier;
    },
```

This returns the error:

```
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
                Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

**Which brings me to my question**

Is there a way to coerce ID to resolve to an int instead of a string? I would like to avoid having to remap all the fields in `Book` just to cast ID to a string

Comment: Use Int type instead of ID in graphql?

Comment: I think that would result in a loss of information. The `ID` type can have programmatic applications (like in the Apollo Client cache), which I would not want to lose.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the behavior of the scalar -- it's parsed as a string because that's what the spec specifies. You can just convert the string into a scalar like this:

```
await models.Book.findByPk(parseInt(id, 10));
```

However, you *could* also just use the `Int` scalar instead of `ID`. The biggest drawback to this approach is that you won't be able to switch to a different kind of ID (like a UUID) without introducing a breaking change to your schema. Using an Int instead of an ID will *not* impact caching done by Apollo Client -- as long as the field is named `id` or `_id`, it will be used in the cache key regardless of its type.

Comment: I must have written the question in an unclear way. My problem is not parsing the int as it comes in. The issue is that when I try to serialize my model, the id is already an Int, but gql expects the return to come as an ID, i.e. a string

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the response. A resolver can return an integer or a string for an ID field, so it sounds like however your GraphQL type is represented in TypeScript is wrong (i.e. in TS, that field should be typed as `string | number`)

Comment: Exactly! However, I'm using using this https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator to automatically generate the annotation, and thus must use follow the graphql policy that ID is always a string

Comment: It's not so much a "policy" as just a [bug with that library](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/2588)

Comment: See [this section of the spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-ID) for reference as to why either string or number are acceptable. Anyway, unless that issue with GraphQL Code Generator is resolved, I would recommended just sticking to `Int` type. There is not real drawback unless you're anticipating changing the column type in the database in the future.